# CLOB WRITE WITH OO4O

Tags: clob

I get the error : OIP-04908: This operation is not permitted on a Null LOB when
Set MyClOB_0 = lOraDynaset_0.Fields("FILE_BODY").Value
lOraDynaset_0.Edit
amount_written = MyClOB_0.Write(buffer, chunksize, ORALOB_FIRST_PIECE)

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem when trying to insert into an Oracle CLOB field.

I got around it by:

1. Setting the Oracle field to 'Empty' (the VB6 keyword Empty - e.g. MyClOB_0.Value = Empty)
2. Performing the insert (e.g. lOraDynaset_0.Update)
3. Editing the dynaset record (e.g. lOraDynaset_0.Edit)
4. Setting the Clob field value to what you want it
5. Performing the update (e.g. lOraDynaset_0.Update)

Hope this helps (sorry if its not clear)

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, but you deserve an upvote.